# How to find an open set that will map one-to-one and onto?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the set $T = \{(u,v): -1 < u < 0\}$ (and v is without bound). I want to find an open set $S \subset \Bbb C$ so that $e^z$ will map one-to-one and onto T.

My attempt:

Let $z = x + iy$.
Then ${e^z = e^{x+iy} = e^xe^{iy} = e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y)})$

Now I'm not sure what to do. I notice that if we let $y\to \infty$ then each of the trigonometric functions will oscillate between (-1,1). Now it gets tricky to think about. sin(y) gives the v-coordinate in the mapping and we want that to be without bound. I think that $e^x$ therefore must increase without bound. So would $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$? But then this means that the u-coordinate would grow without bound as well.

So now I'm confused.

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Convert to polar and draw a picture.

Comment: Are you suggesting to convert

$u = e^xcos(y)$,

$v = e^xsin(y)$

into polar?

Then $u^2 + v^2 = (e^xcos(y))^2+(e^xsin(y))^2 = e^(2x)(cos(y)^2+sin(y)^2) = e^{2x}$?

So $r = {\sqrt{u^2+v^2}} = {\sqrt{e^(2x)}} = e^x$?

Then $y = arctan(sin(y)/cos(y))?$.

I am completely lost by this question, sorry.

Comment: I was suggesting what Cameron wrote up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that we can rewrite $T$ in polar coordinates as the set of points $re^{i\theta}$ with $\frac\pi2<\theta<\frac{3\pi}2$ and $0<r<-\sec\theta.$ Next, note that $e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy},$ so that we just need $-\frac\pi2<y<\frac\pi2$ and $0<e^x<-\sec y.$ Observing that $0<e^x$ for all real $x,$ we can equivalently rewrite the latter inequality as $x<\ln(-\sec y).$

The key observation, here, is that $e^xe^{iy}$ is basically in polar form already, with $r=e^x$ and $y=\theta,$ so it's a very natural thing to consider.

Comment: Really good, it makes sense! Thank you so much! I'll have to think about what happens when we change T to be other stuff. Do you have any suggested resources I can look at to really understand this?

Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite sure I get this.

How did you get $0 < r < -sec \theta$?

I can see how you got theta and the reason for it being in the region it's in. But how did you get -sec(y)? Is it because you want to give v = sin(y) some leeway to go from $(-\infty,\infty)$? Doesn't $e^x$ affect both cos(y) and sin(y)? I don't know if it makes sense, but how do we know that we catch all points in T? Also could r ever be (in some other problem) such that 2 < r < something?

Comment: I'm glad you see where the bounds on $\theta$ come from. All that's left is to translate $-1<x$ into polar terms. Bearing in mind that $\cos\theta<0$ for $\frac\pi2<\theta<\frac{3\pi}2,$ we simpky make the substitution $x=r\cos\theta$ to get $-1<r\cos\theta,$ whence dividing by the negative quantity $\cos\theta$ gives us the equivalent inequality $$-\frac1{\cos\theta}>r,$$ which we can rewrite as $r<-\sec\theta.$ Finally, since we always have $r\ge0,$ and since $r=0$ only at the origin (which isn't included in $T$), then we have $0<r<-\sec\theta.$

Comment: I will leave it to you to verify that $$T=\left\{re^{i\theta}\mid\frac\pi2<\theta<\frac{3\pi}2,0<r<-\sec\theta\right\}.$$ That said, let me know if you get hung up on the verification. Now, once that's done, we need to make sure that $e^xe^{iy}$ lies in this polar version of $T.$ That is, we must make sure that $\frac\pi2<y<\frac{3\pi}2$ and that $0<e^x<\sec y,$ as mentioned above. Does that clear things up?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a test this Friday so I will take a look at it again after I finish the current chapter I'm on.